# impossible to extend maven plugin configuration

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin, plexus

I am trying to extend the maven plugin: hibernate3 (org.codehaus).  All I want to do is extend their base plugin class and change some functionality.  The plugin compiles and installs just fine (after using [maven-inherit-plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20110912062319/http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-inherit-plugin/plugin-info.html) [note: [development of maven-inherit-plugin has moved to GitHub](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.construct/tree/master/maven-inherit-plugin)]), however at runtime I end up with trouble.  For some reason, maven expects there to be a class named Component in the same package as my plugin; I'm not exactly sure why this is -- it seems to be caused by the plexus container.  It seems like I should extend the org.codehaus.mojo.hibernate3.exporter.Component from the parent plugin, but ... well the author has decided that class is final.

Clearly extending maven plugins (at least hibernate3) more [difficult that it first appears](http://blog.aggregat4.net/extending-existing-maven-2-plugins-is-harder), and I am better off copying the source and modifying it.

However, if I could somehow tell plexus not to use my configuration object, and instead use the one from the parent plugin, all would be well.  Can this be done (use a delegate configuration object class)?

Comment: Are you extending Mojo or Plexus components? I believe behavior is different.

Comment: Both, the author of the Mojo plug used a separate (plexus "annotated" object) to store the configuration in instead of the mojo itself.